# How to Drag & Drop Table?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, jquery-ui

I followed this [Ryan Bates tutorial](http://railscasts.com/episodes/147-sortable-lists-revised).

Awesome.

I got it to work with lists, but I've been trying to make it work with tables, more specifically the tables rendered in a partial.

```
<table id="habits" data-update-url="<%= sort_habits_url %>">
  <% @habits.each do |habit| %>
    <tbody id="habit_<%= habit.id %>">
      # 2 tr's & 7 td's
    </tbody>
  <% end %>
</table>
```

With the above version the iteration multiples the tables because I am rendering this partial from the home page with `<% rendered @habits %>` so I shouldn't have to include the line `<% @habits.each do |habit| %>`.

So I tried this:

```
<table id="habits" data-update-url="<%= sort_habits_url %>">
  <tbody id="habit_<%= habit.id %>">
    # 2 tr's & 7 td's
  </tbody>
</table>
```

But then only the first table can be dragged. With the first example code only the first iteration of tables can be dragged and dropped.

**habit-sort.js.coffee**

```
jQuery ->
  $('#habits').sortable(
    axis: 'y'
    update: ->
      $.post($(this).data('update-url'), $(this).sortable('serialize'))
  );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If are trying to handle multiple DOMs, you cannot use the DOM ID. So you'll need to replace the id by class.

Working with multiple tbodys and sorting TRs inside each tbody: http://jsfiddle.net/aron_aron/1jjhdtj2/2/

Also, if you bind `<table id="habits"`, the sortable content will be the entire tbody html content.

**Update**

Let me try to do a simple explanation on how sortable works.

When you call `$( "#item" ).sortable()`, you will be able to sort(change the position) of every children in the root of the #item.

What does it mean?

If you have the following html:

```
<div class="sortable_tables">
    <table class="sortable_bodys">
        <tbody class="sortable_trs">
          <tr class="sortable_tds">
              <td>ID 1</td>
              <td>Item Name 1</td>
              <td>Action</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
```

So you can call the `.sortable()` at any level, depending on the expected behavior.

For example, if you want to sort a entire tables, just call `$( ".sortable_tables" ).sortable()`, so you will be able to change the position of any html element created inside `<div class="sortable_tables">`

But let's say that you want to sort the rows in the table. So, to sort TRs, you need to call the parent html `.select()`. TR's parent is a tbody, so `$( ".sortable_trs" ).sortable()` you will be able to sort TRs inside each tbody with the `sortable_trs` class

Comment: Thanks Aron! So I did it like this because I want the whole table to move `<table class="habits" data-update-url="<%= sort_habits_url %>">
  <tbody>`. That has enabled me to drag all the tables, but now they won't drop in any other position besides the position they are currently in.

Comment: Aron for some reason if I do this `<table >
    <tbody class="habits">` the table rows get split up and don't drag together even though `tbody` surrounds them. I don't get why it doesn't work like your's for me.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification :] I have a better grasp of it now. I still can't get the dragging to be dropped in a new position though. When dropped it falls back to original position. I have `<table class="sortable_bodys">` now, which addressed the splitting up issue :]

Comment: That's even if I use: `$(function() {
    $( ".sortable_bodys" ).sortable();
    $( ".sortable_bodys" ).disableSelection();
  });` or my original `jQuery ->
  $(".sortable_bodys").sortable(
    axis: 'y'
    update: ->
      $.post($(this).data('update-url'), $(this).sortable('serialize'))
  );`

Comment: I'm not experienced with rails, the generated html is similar with this one: http://jsfiddle.net/aron_aron/1jjhdtj2/3/  ? Do you have multiple tbodies inside a table?

Comment: As I was drifting off into my dream world, in the quiet of the night, I had an  AhHa moment! We needed to sort it around the partial being called not within the partial: `<div class="sortable_partial"><%= render @habits %></div>` Thanks again for your help Aron!